Exit code 1 in simple express node.js server (VSCode)
I'm using VSCode and created a small vue / express / node.js project.
While running my server I noticed that when I close it using ctrl+c in the VSCode terminal (power shell), there is a red circle with a cross next to the initial command line that when hovered tells me the command exited with an exit code of 1.
My assumption is that it should exit with a code of 0. Here is my code, run with node server.js
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import http from 'http';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

// Our express app
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 8080...");
});

function shutdown() {
    console.log('Shutdown initiated...');
    server.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during server close:', err);
            process.exit(1); 
        } else {
            console.log('Server closed successfully');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });

   // Force shutdown after 5 seconds if not closed
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.error('Force shutting down after timeout...');
        process.exit(1); 
    }, 5000);
}

// Handle termination signals
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('Received SIGTERM');
    shutdown();
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('Received SIGINT');
    shutdown();
});

It logs:
Received SIGINT
Shutdown initiated...
Server closed successfully

When I run it in a terminal outside of VSCode, it just shows the above same logs but no error code mentioned.
Also, when, in VSCode, I add a Shutdown() right after the log of listening, it exits with a code of 0 properly.
I don't have any other interaction with my server (like asking for files, opened DB connection or anything else). I just open it / close it with ctrl+c.
Could it be just a VSCode issue or am I missing something? I'm not sure what else I could try to narrow down the issue.
I also added a block of code to display exit code used:
process.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`Process exited with code: ${code}`);
});

And it displayed 0 both in VSCode (despite the red circle/arrow saying exit 1) and outside.
